# If I reset my hero class, will I get back my gems?

Tags: growcastle

I'm playing GrowCastle version 1.23.8 on my cell phone. I was checking my hero's class, and I saw that I chose the left branch of the 'Druid' class, but the one on the right is better for my current strategy. There is a button that says 'Reset class'.
If I use this option, will I get back the 30 gems I've spent on my current character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the ‘reset class’ Button does not give you your gems back, The button is only there if you do not like your current class.